# Payload in redux is always undefined, although data is available

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) application in which I use redux / redux saga.

Although I receive data from the backend (so there is a payload that I can see in the browsers network tab), it is sent to my reducer as `undefined`. I thought that it might be due to the payload type and set it to `any`. Still, it doesn't want to work.

Here is my setup (shown in simplified form):

**actions.ts**

```
export const getSomeStuff: ActionType<any> = (data: any) => ({
  type: actionTypes.GET_SOME_STUFF,
  payload: data,
});

export const getSomeStuffSuccess: ActionType<any> = (data: any) => ({
  type: actionTypes.GET_SOME_STUFF_SUCCESS,
  payload: data,
});
```

**actionTypes.ts**

```
export const actionTypes = {
  GET_SOME_STUFF: 'GET_SOME_STUFF',
  GET_SOME_STUFF_SUCCESS: 'GET_SOME_STUFF_SUCCESS',
};
```

**reducers.ts**

```
interface customInterface {
  list: any;
}

export const initialState: customInterface = {
  list: null,
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action: ReturnType<ActionType>) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_SOME_STUFF_SUCCESS:
      return {
        list: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**sagas.ts**

```
function* getSomeStuffSaga(action: ReturnType<ActionType>) {
  try {
    const payload: any = yield call(api.getSomeStuff, action.payload);
    yield put(getSomeStuffSuccess(payload));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

function* watchGetSomeStuffSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_SOME_STUFF, getSomeStuffSaga);
}

export default function* sagas() {
  yield fork(watchGetSomeStuffSaga);
}
```

**The api call**

```
  getSomeStuff = (data: any) => {
    http.get(`my/custom/endpoint`) as Promise<any>;
  };
```

**The dispatch**

```
dispatch(getSomeStuff('someStringParametersPassed'));
```

**Simplified payload I get (in the browsers network tab)**

```
{
   "items": [
      {
         "id":"123456789",
         "stuff":{
            "generalStuff": {
               ...
            },
            "basicStuff": {
               ...
            }
         }
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate key in `actionTypes`

Comment: @SaGaR Fixed it - just a typo while creating this post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you simply forgot to `return` in the api call:

```
getSomeStuff = (data: any) => {
      return http.get(`my/custom/endpoint`) as Promise<any>;
  };

:)
```

Comment: Yes! That was the problem that I discovered last night when I hovered over the line in vscode :D.. Thanks :)